# checkout page not working on multi-lingual website

Tags: checkout, localisation, magento-2.1.7

I am building on bilingual Magento website 
**Magento version 2.1.7 CE**

I just realized the checkout page on page on our french website is not working :(

```
https://thailandfightgear.fr/checkout/
```

on the English website, the page is working (but pretty slow, even on production mode) :

```
https://thailandfightgear.com/checkout/
```

I tried to recompile the website

```
  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
  php bin/magento setup:di:compile

  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR
```

but it didn't help.

Any idea how to fix the problem who be very useful. I would like to fix that soon :-)

Thanks in advance for your help.

while loading the checkout page I have these errors :

> theme.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stellar is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (theme.js:28)
>
> ```
> at fire (jquery.js:3232)
>
> at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
>
> at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
>
> at theme.js:27
>
> at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>
> at Module.check (require.js:866)
>
> at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
>
> at require.js:132
>
> at require.js:1156 (anonymous) @ theme.js:28 fire @ jquery.js:3232 add @ jquery.js:3291 jQuery.fn.ready @ jquery.js:3542 (anonymous) @
> ```
>
> theme.js:27 execCb @ require.js:1650 check @ require.js:866
>
> (anonymous) @ require.js:1113 (anonymous) @ require.js:132 (anonymous)
>
> @ require.js:1156 each @ require.js:57 emit @ require.js:1155 check @
>
> require.js:917 enable @ require.js:1143 init @ require.js:774
>
> callGetModule @ require.js:1170 completeLoad @ require.js:1564
>
> onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671 (index):1200 Uncaught TypeError:
>
> $(...).swMegamenu is not a function
>
> ```
> at (index):1200
>
> at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>
> at Module.check (require.js:866)
>
> at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
>
> at require.js:132
>
> at require.js:1156
>
> at each (require.js:57)
>
> at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
>
> at Module.check (require.js:917)
>
> at Module.enable (require.js:1143) (anonymous) @ (index):1200 execCb @ require.js:1650 check @ require.js:866 (anonymous) @
> ```
>
> require.js:1113 (anonymous) @ require.js:132 (anonymous) @
>
> require.js:1156 each @ require.js:57 emit @ require.js:1155 check @
>
> require.js:917 enable @ require.js:1143 init @ require.js:774
>
> callGetModule @ require.js:1170 completeLoad @ require.js:1564
>
> onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671 dataPost.js:13 Uncaught TypeError:
>
> $.widget is not a function
>
> ```
> at dataPost.js:13
>
> at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>
> at Module.check (require.js:866)
>
> at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
>
> at require.js:132
>
> at require.js:1156
>
> at each (require.js:57)
>
> at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
>
> at Module.check (require.js:917)
>
> at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113) (anonymous) @ dataPost.js:13 execCb @ require.js:1650 check @ require.js:866
> ```
>
> (anonymous) @ require.js:1113 (anonymous) @ require.js:132 (anonymous)
>
> @ require.js:1156 each @ require.js:57 emit @ require.js:1155 check @
>
> require.js:917 (anonymous) @ require.js:1113 (anonymous) @
>
> require.js:132 (anonymous) @ require.js:1156 each @ require.js:57 emit
>
> @ require.js:1155 check @ require.js:917 enable @ require.js:1143 init
>
> @ require.js:774 callGetModule @ require.js:1170 completeLoad @
>
> require.js:1544 onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
>
> jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>
> property 'timepicker' of undefined
>
> ```
> at jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js:18
>
> at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>
> at Module.check (require.js:866)
>
> at Module.enable (require.js:1143)
>
> at Module.init (require.js:774)
>
> at callGetModule (require.js:1170)
>
> at Object.completeLoad (require.js:1544)
>
> at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (require.js:1671)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution. As crazy as it sound **the solution was to combine the js.**

I am copying again here the errors messages that i had on checkout page, in the case somebody got the same, maybe it can help somebody if he manage to find this post with looking at theses errors.

The template we are using Smartwave/porto (the error only occurred on second store, not the main one).

```
$(...).stellar is not a function
$(...).swMegamenu is not a function
$.widget is not a function
```